# Как изменить шрифт, не используя методы вроде toUpperCase?

Tags: java

Например, чтобы при вводе `"привет"`, на выходе было `"ПРИВЕТ"`.
Но без использования метода `toUpperCase()`.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String text = in.next();
        // пробовал разные варианты, но пока не хватает знаний
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лучше, конечно, через кодировку, но есть и такой (наваристо-забористый) вариант:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    // Массив замены символов
    public static Map<char, char> map = new HashMap<>() {{
        put('а', 'А');
        put('б', 'Б');
        ...
        put('я', 'Я');
    }};

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String text = in.next();

        // Выходная строка
        String output = "";
        for(int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
            // Получить значение из входной строки
            char c = text.charAt(i);

            // Получить значение из массива замены
            char value = Main.map.get(c);

            // Если не Null, то прибавить к выходной строке значение (value)
            // из массива замены, иначе сам символ из входной строки
            output += value? value: c;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Именно такой наваристо-забористый вариант мне и подходит)

Answer (score 3):

См. таблицу символов [UTF-8](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8). В ней сначала идут заглавные буквы, потом строчные. Символ `char` в `java` хранит в себе десятичное значение кода символа. Чтобы из строчной буквы получить заглавную, нужно сместить код вниз на `32` и наоборот.

---

Заглавные латинские буквы: `A - Z` ⇒ коды символов `65 - 90`.
Строчные латинские буквы: `a - z` ⇒ коды символов `97 - 122`.

Аналогичная ситуация с кириллическими буквами:

Заглавные кириллические буквы: `А - Я` ⇒ коды символов `1040 - 1071`.
Строчные кириллические буквы: `а - я` ⇒ коды символов `1072 - 1103`.

*Отдельная история: `Ё` ⇒ `1025`, `ё` ⇒ `1105`.*

---

Пример кода:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(toLowerCase("СЛОВА_С-БУКВОЙ Ё"));
    System.out.println(toLowerCase("UPPER=WORDS_lower*words"));

    // слова_с-буквой ё
    // upper=words_lower*words
}

private static String toLowerCase(String upperCase) {
    char[] charArr = upperCase.toCharArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < charArr.length; i++) {
        if (charArr[i] == 1025) {
            charArr[i] = 1105;
        } else if (charArr[i] >= 65 && charArr[i] <= 90
                || charArr[i] >= 1040 && charArr[i] <= 1071) {
            charArr[i] = (char) (charArr[i] + 32);
        }
    }

    return String.valueOf(charArr);
}
```

Comment: Можно просто `charArr[i] += 32`.