# Замена противоположных букв в алфавите

Tags: java, replace

Задача: поменять буквы в пользовательском вводе на противоположные в алфавите, вроде легко, метод `replace` в помощь, но при замене букв на противоположные, они меняются обратно, например: строка "abcdfgz", - меняю "a" на "z" и "z" на "a", соответственно должно получиться: "zbcdfga" но получается: "abcdfga", так как при второй замене уже замененная первый раз буква меняется во второй, как сделать так, чтобы буквы менялись на противоположные в алфавите, только 1 раз?

Вот мой код, я там пробую только 2 буквы:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Program {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String vvod = scan.nextLine();

        String res = vvod.replaceAll("a", "z").replaceAll("z", "a");
        System.out.print(res);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Каждую строку в `Java` можно представить в виде массива символов `char`. Каждый символ `char` имеет свой числовой код. Оперируя этими числами, можно изменять буквы по какой-либо определенной логике.

См. ответ на вопрос [Как изменить шрифт, не используя методы вроде toUpperCase?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1104200/236980)

Для данного случая:

```
private static String replace(String text) {
    char[] charArr = text.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < charArr.length; i++) {
        if (charArr[i] >= 'a' && charArr[i] <= 'z') {
            charArr[i] = (char) ('z' - charArr[i] + 'a');
        } else if (charArr[i] >= 'A' && charArr[i] <= 'Z') {
            charArr[i] = (char) ('Z' - charArr[i] + 'A');
        }
    }
    return String.valueOf(charArr);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str1 = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    String str2 = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    String str3 = "aBcDeFgHiJkLmNoPqRsTuVwXyZ";

    System.out.println(str1 + " | " + replace(str1));
    System.out.println(str2 + " | " + replace(str2));
    System.out.println(str3 + " | " + replace(str3));

    // abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz | zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba
    // ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ | ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA
    // aBcDeFgHiJkLmNoPqRsTuVwXyZ | zYxWvUtSrQpOnMlKjIhGfEdCbA

    System.out.println(replace(replace(str1)).equals(str1)); // true
    System.out.println(replace(replace(str2)).equals(str2)); // true
    System.out.println(replace(replace(str3)).equals(str3)); // true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public enum Alphabet {
    a('z'),
    z('a');

    private char letter;

    Alphabet(char letter) {
        this.letter = letter;
    }

    public char getLetter() {
        return letter;
    }
}


import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String vvod = scan.nextLine();
        char[] reverse = vvod.toCharArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < reverse.length; i++) {
            reverse[i] = Alphabet.valueOf(String.valueOf(reverse[i])).getLetter();
        }
        System.out.println(new String(reverse));
    }
}
```

Comment: reverse переворачивает строку, задача поменять буквы на противоположные

Comment: На противоположные с другой стороны алфавита

Comment: Тогда такой вариант. В enum надо записать весь алфавит в том виде как его надо перевести. На данный момент программа умеет работать только с символами "a" и "z"